# c# How to implement a disposing method to my data class for disposing connection

Tags: c#

I use an abstract class for my data entities. This class already has an inheritance to TypedTable.
Recently I came into the need of mantaining my conection object opened during the class operations and only closing it when I dispose the entity.
As double inheritance to "disposable" is not possible, I've tried to implement the disposing method by overriding the one on TypedTable, but it never gets called.

```
public abstract class TypedTable<TRow> : TypedTableBase<TRow> where TRow : TypedRow
{
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Context != null) Context.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

My entity objects are generally consumed by instantiating them, calling the get method and leaving it alone after using the data. So my intention is that is automatically disposed when the caller method ends.

Anyone knows how to acomplish what I need?

Comment: `"and leaving it alone after using the data"` - If your object is disposable, why not use it in something like a `using` block so it gets disposed?

Comment: Hey David. The main concern would be refactoring the entire application (it's really big) but also should still be possible to do a direct get of the data in one line.

Comment: If the application isn't disposing of resources then modifying the application seems to be a reasonable expectation.  As for the "one line" concern, how is that even applicable?  Each method on the object can still be called in one line.  But the object itself should be disposed if it's managing disposable resources.

Comment: The Dispose has to expressly called, it doesn't happen automatically. It sounds like that's why it's not firing. This is done by calling obj.Dispose() or wrapping it in a using block as David suggested.